# How to calculate volume of a solid under a given surface with double intergrals?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate the volume of the solid under the surface $z = 6x + 4y + 7$ and above the plane $z = 0$ over a given rectangle $R = \{ (x, y): -4 \leq x \leq 1, 1 \leq y \leq 4 \}$?

I know I have to integrate some function, but since the surface takes both positive and negative values I don't know what to integrate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! Please provide some work on the problem. I gave you a hint (see answer below) to give an idea how to approach a problem of that type. Want to try it and let me know if you have any further questions? If yes, please post them as comments to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- Find the equation of the curve of the surface where you have $z=0$ over your region (that will be a curve in $x,y$).
- Now draw the region with your curve there and indicate where you have $z>0$ and where $z<0$.
- Set up the double integral just over the piece where $z > 0$.
- Evaluate

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- Graph the $x$, $y$, and $z$ intercepts of the given surface (plane) to see where in the $xy$ plane you have $z>0$.
- Adjust the rectangle you are integrating over to only cover area where $z>0$. It may help to draw the rectangle in the $xy$ plane. (It looks like in this question $y$ needs no adjustment, but $x$ needs to be within a smaller interval than $[-4,1]$.)
- Write down the double integral of $z$ integrating over $x$ and $y$ as specified by your found limits. Integrate.